# Why does the compiler not recognize Math.PI()?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

UPDATE: New problem in the code (see below)
For Java homework, we need to compute the cos and sin values at each interval of pi/4 of the unit circle and print it out.But mines is rounding incorrectly, even though I used the rounding technique the instructions provided using the assignment of a double doubleName and doubleName = Math.round(doubleName* 100) / 100.0.

The outcome should be:
Radians: (cos, sin)
0.0: 1.0, 0.0
0.79: 0.7, 0.71
1.57: 0.0, 1.0
2.36: -0.71, 0.7
3.14: -1.0, 0.0
3.93: -0.7, -0.71
4.71: 0.0, -1.0
5.5: 0.71, -0.71

But my output is:
Radians: (cos, sin)
0.0: 1.0, 0.0
0.79: 0.7, 0.71
1.58: -0.01, 1.0
2.37: -0.72, 0.7
3.16: -1.0, -0.02
3.95: -0.69, -0.72
4.74: 0.03, -1.0
5.53: 0.73, -0.68

My code:

```js
public class UnitCircle extends ConsoleProgram {
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("Radians: (cos, sin)");
    for (double i = 0; i <= 2 * Math.PI; i += Math.PI / 4) {
      i = Math.round(i * 100.0) / 100.0;
      double x = Math.cos(i);
      x = Math.round(x * 100.0) / 100.0;
      double y = Math.sin(i);
      y = Math.round(y * 100.0) / 100.0;
      System.out.println(i + ": " + x + ", " + y);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `Math.PI` ? It's not a function, but a constant instead.

Comment: Please don't include images that aren't necessary in your posts. Both of the links you provided could have been posted as text instead, which means they are easy to read (and you wouldn't need help posting them). Images should only be used when there is no other way to demonstrate the problem, and that doesn't apply to either of the cases where you've used them here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Math.PI(). Have a look at the Java Math Class Documentation found here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

There is no PI method, however there is a PI Field. So try:

```
Math.PI
```